# Prenatal hyperkinetic dysfunction and its effect on endurace

Tags: physiology, muscles, kinetics, health, dopamine

Do people with an hyperkinetic dysfuntion have a better endurance?  Are they fitter in cause of their Dopamine-overdose or any other reason? I have a case, where someone does not do any sports, but has an endurance way better than most of others who does no sports. He even can compete with some amateur athletes.

Just for comprehension: He does not eat well, sits most of the time (during work, at home), does not do any other activities except eSports (onlinegames).

Maybe someone has an answer, at least I hope you have.

Comment: cross posted here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/do-people-with-prenatal-hyperkinetic-dysfunction-have-better-endurace

Comment: changed to not be a crosspost